# is there a cardboard/VR emulator available?

Tags: emulators, google-cardboard

i need to check out the content of some VR apps, but i dont have a set of VR glasses. is there any app or emulator or anything that can just show me the split 2-D views side by side?

i dont need the "full experience". a basic rendering will do just fine

i scoured the web but couldnt find anything like this

thanks!

here's a screenshot. i'm using droid4x
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Just run the app. The Google Cardboard is just a way of attaching the lenses and phone to your face. The phone doesn't know whether it's in the headset or not. The app just displays the two views on the screen, whether it's in the headset or not.

---

Note that this **only** applies to Google Cardboard apps, not to Samsung Gear VR. Gear VR has its own electronics supplying extra sensor data to the phone, so apps written to work with Gear VR will only work with an actual Gear VR headset.

Comment: hi thanks. i tried but all i get is 2 tiny images on the bottom. i just added a screenshot. please advise.